# MongoDB Query in Array of Arrays and add if not present

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I have

```
{ 
 "Districts" : 
    [{ "name" : "Krishna" 
     , "Locations" : [{ "name" : "Vijayawada"} 
                     ,{ "name" : "Machilipatnam"}]}
     , { "name" : "Guntur"
     , "Locations" : [{ "name" : "Satenpalli"}]}
    ]
 , "_id" : 1 
 , "name" : "Andhra Pradesh"
}
```

I am trying to create one more Location "Achampet" if District name is "Guntur" so the result should be this below. The result should be the same even if I try to add Achampet more than once.

```
{ 
 "Districts" : 
    [{ "name" : "Krishna" 
     , "Locations" : [{ "name" : "Vijayawada"} 
                     ,{ "name" : "Machilipatnam"}]}
     , { "name" : "Guntur"
     , "Locations" : [{ "name" : "Satenpalli"}
                     ,{ "name" : "Achampet"}]}
    ]
 , "_id" : 1 
 , "name" : "Andhra Pradesh"
}
```

But my java code doesn't work

```
DBObject newLoc = new BasicDBObject("Districts", new BasicDBObject("name", distName).append("Locations", new BasicDBObject("name", locName)));
            if (statesColl.findOne(newLoc) == null) {
                DBObject updateLoc = new BasicDBObject("$push", newLoc);
                statesColl.update(queryDist, updateLoc);
            }
```

It is creating a new District everytime I try to add a location. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it using the [`$ positional`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator in Java:

```
...
DBObject selectQuery = new BasicDBObject("_id", 1); // Matches the document
selectQuery.append("Districts.name", distName); // Matches the element in the array where District name = Guntur

BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject();
updateFields.put("Districts.$.Locations", new BasicDBObject("name":"Achampet"));

DBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject("$addToSet", updateFields);
statesColl.update(selectQuery, updateQuery); 
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This above code is adding Achampet twice in my code. How can I check if a particular Location is already in the collection?

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question in the post, please edit.  I have edited my code to use [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).  That will only add to the array, if the element is not already present.

Comment: Modified my question accordingly. Thanks